# How to configure full synchronization instead of incremental?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, alfresco, alfresco-ldap

AFAIK Alfresco CE at startup performs only incremental synchronization with LDAP-AD. When I installed Alfresco and configured synchronization with LDAP-AD was performed a full synchronization. All the fields that I declared was displayed in the user profile. Now, I decided to add a few more fields. For example, `skype` and `companyfax`.

But they are not displayed.

Part of the `alfresco-global.properties` (similarly, in `/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Authentication/ldap/ldap1/ldap-ad-authentication.properties`):

```
    ...
    ldap.authentication.active=false
    ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
    ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s@...
    ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
    ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://...:389
    ldap.synchronization.active=true
    ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=Alfresco@...
    ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=...
    ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=0
    ldap.synchronization.attributeBatchSize=0

    ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(objectclass\=group)
    ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=group)(!(whenChanged<\={0})))
    ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(&(objectclass\=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512))
    ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512)(!(whenChanged<\={0})))

    ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=cn\=Builtin,dc\=...,dc\=local
    ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=cn\=Users,dc\=...,dc\=local
    #ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=whenChanged
    #synchronization.import.cron=* */40 * * * ?
    ntlm.authentication.sso.enabled=true
    passthru.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=Admin,BykovAN
    passthru.authentication.domain=...
    passthru.authentication.servers=...\\...
    passthru.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=Admin,BykovAN
    ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=modifyTimestamp
    ldap.synchronization.timestampFormat=yyyyMMddHHmmss'.0Z'
    ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=sAMAccountName

    ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider=largeHomeFolderProvider
    ldap.synchronization.groupType=group
    ldap.synchronization.personType=user
    ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=member
    ldap.synchronization.enableProgressEstimation=true
    ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=displayName
    ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=department
    ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=email
    ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=department
    ldap.synchronization.userJobTitleAttributeName=title
    ldap.synchronization.userLocationAttributeName=description
    ldap.synchronization.userTelephoneAttributeName=telephoneNumber

    ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
    ldap.synchronization.groupDisplayNameAttributeName=displayName
    ldap.synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false

    #synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=true
    #synchronization.syncOnStartup=true
    #synchronization.autoCreatePeopleOnLogin=true
...
```

In the logs I see that the synchronization is not performed:

```
 ...
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,891  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronizing users and groups with user registry 'ldap1'
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,921  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Retrieving groups changed since 01.03.2017 14:46:18 from user registry 'ldap1'
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,941  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=1 Group Analysis: Commencing batch of 0 entries
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,942  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=1 Group Analysis: Completed batch of 0 entries
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,945  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Retrieving users changed since 07.03.2017 9:13:44 from user registry 'ldap1'
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,963  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Commencing batch of 0 entries
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,963  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Completed batch of 0 entries
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,975  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Finished synchronizing users and groups with user registry 'ldap1'
 2017-03-07 10:07:39,976  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Processed users: 0 groups: 0
...
```

---

I changed LDAP queries to (removed `whenChanged`):

```
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(objectclass\=group)
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectClass\=group))
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(&(objectclass\=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512))
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=user))
```

Then restart Alfresco and each time it performs a full synchronization. It seems that now everything is OK. Or am I wrong?..

```
...
2017-03-07 11:42:30,314  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronizing users and groups with user registry 'ldap1'
2017-03-07 11:42:30,341  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Retrieving groups changed since 01.03.2017 14:46:18 from user registry 'ldap1'
2017-03-07 11:42:30,431  WARN  [sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Failed to resolve member of group 'Users' with distinguished name: CN=S-1-5-11,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=...,DC=local
2017-03-07 11:42:30,431  WARN  [sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Failed to resolve member of group 'Users' with distinguished name: CN=S-1-5-4,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=...,DC=local
2017-03-07 11:42:30,437  WARN  [sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Failed to resolve member of group 'The performance log users' with distinguished name: CN=S-1-5-20,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=...,DC=local
2017-03-07 11:42:30,626  WARN  [sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Failed to resolve member of group 'DCOM Users' with distinguished name: CN=PK-535-W8,OU=Computers,OU=OIT,OU=...,DC=...,DC=local
2017-03-07 11:42:30,685  WARN  [sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Failed to resolve member of group 'DCOM Users' with distinguished name: CN=PK-265-XP,OU=Computers,OU=FSO,OU=...,DC=...,DC=local
2017-03-07 11:42:30,697  WARN  [sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Failed to resolve member of group 'Pre-Windows 2000 access' with distinguished name: CN=S-1-5-11,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=...,DC=local
2017-03-07 11:42:30,698  WARN  [sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Failed to resolve member of group 'Windows authorization access group' with distinguished name: CN=S-1-5-9,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=...,DC=local
2017-03-07 11:42:30,704  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=1 Group Analysis: Commencing batch of 19 entries
2017-03-07 11:42:30,874  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=1 Group Analysis: Processed 19 entries out of 19. 100% complete. Rate: 111 per second. 0 failures detected.
2017-03-07 11:42:30,875  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=1 Group Analysis: Completed batch of 19 entries
2017-03-07 11:42:30,896  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=3 Group Creation and Association Deletion: Commencing batch of 4 entries
2017-03-07 11:42:30,897  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=3 Group Creation and Association Deletion: Processed 4 entries out of 4. 100% complete. Rate: 4000 per second. 0 failures detected.
2017-03-07 11:42:30,897  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=3 Group Creation and Association Deletion: Completed batch of 4 entries
2017-03-07 11:42:30,900  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Retrieving users changed since 07.03.2017 9:13:44 from user registry 'ldap1'
2017-03-07 11:42:30,939  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Commencing batch of 529 entries
2017-03-07 11:42:32,015  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Processed 100 entries out of 529. 19% complete. Rate: 92 per second. 0 failures detected.
2017-03-07 11:42:32,777  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Processed 200 entries out of 529. 38% complete. Rate: 108 per second. 0 failures detected.
2017-03-07 11:42:33,426  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Processed 300 entries out of 529. 57% complete. Rate: 120 per second. 0 failures detected.
2017-03-07 11:42:34,025  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Processed 400 entries out of 529. 76% complete. Rate: 129 per second. 0 failures detected.
2017-03-07 11:42:34,640  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Processed 500 entries out of 529. 95% complete. Rate: 135 per second. 0 failures detected.
2017-03-07 11:42:34,791  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Processed 529 entries out of 529. 100% complete. Rate: 137 per second. 0 failures detected.
2017-03-07 11:42:34,791  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Completed batch of 529 entries
2017-03-07 11:42:34,803  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Finished synchronizing users and groups with user registry 'ldap1'
2017-03-07 11:42:34,803  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Processed users: 529 groups: 19
...
```

How to properly configure the full synchronization at the startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Axel Faust](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/16045) gave an exhaustive answer:

[How to configure full synchronization instead of incremental?](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/how-to-configure-full-synchronization-instead-of-incremental/m-p/161744)

It solved my issue.

As said here: [Synchronization configuration properties](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/sync-props.html)

> - `synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly`: specifies whether the scheduled synchronization job is run in differential mode. The default
>     is `true`, which means that the scheduled sync job is run in
>     differential mode (rather than full mode). Regardless of this setting
>     a differential sync can still be triggered when a user who does not
>     yet exist in Alfresco is successfully authenticated.